# Converting characters to string from a selenium list

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get each word from a page and then determine if it matches the searched word. Whenever I get all the text it seems to all be there as strings, but upon printing eachWord one at a time, we see they are just characters. I have tried using .join(), but nothing changes.
Any ideas?

```
x=2
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
count=0

searchedWord = "Login"
allText=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text

print("Words found:")
#print(allText)

allText=''.join(allText)

print(allText)



for eachWord in allText:
    print(eachWord)
    if eachWord==searchedWord:
        print("word found!")
    else:
        time.sleep(x)
        driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allText` is returning string so when you try to iterate it returns character .If it was be array your function works fine but in this situation you don't need to for loop . Use it.

```
if searchedWord in allText:

    print("word found!")

else:
    time.sleep(x)
    browser.refresh()
```

OUTPUT :

```
word found!
```